# How can I share javascript/html among several elements on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have web page with two textboxes on it.  Upon clicking on the first, I have a bootstrap modal that displays with a searchable treeview.  You click an item in the treeview, the modal closes, and the selection appears in the textbox.  Works perfectly!

Now I have decided that for the other textbox I want to do the same thing.  The only difference is the modal has a different title, and the source data for the modal treeview comes from a different endpoint.  All the other javascript to support searching and highlighting within a treeview, opening and closing a modal, etc, is the same.

To get it to work, I duplicated all html for the modals and the js code and just changed the ID's to avoid clashes between the two.  I cannot live with myself for doing this!

So in the end, I have some js and html that work together as a component that I want to reuse on a page among several textboxes or whatever type of widget I may create.  How can I design my app so I can share this code and not duplicate it all over the page?

Comment: You might want to look at **Partial View** in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: The same way you avoid duplicating code in other environments:  encapsulate the functionality in reusable components or functions.  Answers here recommending a specific technology are kind of missing the point, you can (and should) do this in any environment (though the details of exactly how to best do so will depend on which environment or framework you're using, which probably makes this question too broad to be usefully answerable...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot to unpack in this question. High level, to achieve what you're asking with JS…

You could:

1. Build a method that accepts an event object (or jQuery event object) as its argument; and handles extracting extracting data from the attributes of that element, setting the title, AJAXing the treeview, and returning the selection/setting the text box value
2. embed the unique data in data-attributes on each text box
3. set the click event listener to pass the `event.target` element, with its unique `data-` attributes to the method

**Markup:**

```
<input type="text" id="foo" data-endpoint="/path/to/endpoint_1" data-title="Modal Foo" value="" />
```

**JS**

```
function on_click_modal_spawning_textbox( event ) {
  // get the salient data from the `data-` attributes on the `event.target`
  // do modal stuff, programmatically replace the modal title, AJAX treeview, et cetera…
}

// assuming you're using jQuery, otherwise this would be a vanilla `.addEventListener()`
$( document ).on( 'click', 'input[ data-endpoint ]', on_click_modal_spawning_textbox );
```

Comment: thank you!  I ended up doing something nearly exactly like this.  I just had a hard time getting in the right mindset.

Answer (score 2):

I think [webcomponents](https://www.webcomponents.org/) is the way to go. You could create a component that receives the id and other needed data as parameters and then create instances of it...